# Isolated Storage in silverlight application - non consistent behavior

Tags: silverlight-4.0, isolatedstorage

I have a silverlight application which hosted in asp.net web site.

I store some information in .txt file isolated storage, in order to load it next time the application called.

Here I have a strange problem: sometimes the application doesn't find the file!

I checked what exactly happens, and discover that the isolated storage (I checked on Windows 7) composed of set of folders, their names seem as keys/guids.
when the application doesn't find the file, for some reason it goes to another key/guid folder, not to the folder the application saved the file on!
I read about it throughout the net, and understand that the key/guid folders created by microsoft according its security policy.

the code I used to create the isolated storage is:

`IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForSite();`

I tried also

`IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()`

-the same problem.

what can I do?

I'll be glad to detail more, if necessary.

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem- the website which hosts the silverlight application create two domains- one with www and another without.

this was created the two isolated storages, and cause the confusion.